# File transfer using thread

Tags: c, multithreading, file, sockets, pthreads

I am trying to write a file transfer program using threading. The format I am trying to follow is:

```
./server 4501 ..................(will run forever)
./client 4501 add1.txt
./client 4501 bdd1.txt
```

And add1.txt and bdd1.txt will save in server side as add2.txt and bdd2.txt. But after running my code I found that add2.txt contains the characters from add1.txt plus some extra characters.

**

### Updated Solution

**

**Server Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* Preprocessor Directives */

#define NTHREADS 50
#define QUEUE_SIZE 5
#define BUFFER_SIZE 256

/* Global counter locked via mutex */

pthread_t threadid[NTHREADS]; // Thread pool
pthread_mutex_t lock;
int counter = 0;

void *threadworker(void *arg)
{

  int sockfd, rw; // File descriptor and 'read/write' to socket indicator
  char *buffer; // Message buffer
  sockfd = (int) arg; // Getting sockfd from void arg passed in

  buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
  bzero(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);

  rw = read(sockfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE); // Blocks until there is something to be read in the socket

  FILE *fp; 
  fp=fopen("add2.txt","w");
  fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
  //fwrite(buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1, 1, fp);
  //fwrite(buffer,sizeof(char),BUFFER_SIZE, fp);
  fclose(fp);
  printf("%d\n",strlen(buffer));
  printf("the file was received successfully\n");
  printf("the new file created is add2.txt\n");     

  if (rw < 0)
  {
    perror("Error reading form socket, exiting thread");
    pthread_exit(0);
  }

  //printf("New message received: %s", buffer); // String already has newline
  bzero(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
  //sprintf(buffer, "Acknowledgement from TID:0x%x", pthread_self());

  /*rw = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));

  if (rw < 0)
  {
    perror("Error writing to socket, exiting thread");
    pthread_exit(0);
  }*/

  /* Critical section */

  /*printf("Requesting mutex lock...\n");
  pthread_mutex_lock (&lock);
  printf("Current counter value: %d, upping by 1...\n", counter);
  counter++;
  pthread_mutex_unlock (&lock);
  printf("Done! Mutex unlocked again, new counter value: %d\n", counter);
  */
  close(sockfd);
  //printf("TID:0x%x served request, exiting thread\n", pthread_self());
  pthread_exit(0);

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  /* Variable declarations */

  int serv_sockfd, new_sockfd; //Socket identifiers for server and incoming clients
  struct addrinfo flags; // Params used to establish listening socket
  struct addrinfo *host_info; // Resultset for localhost address info, set by getaddrinfo()

  socklen_t addr_size; // Client address size since we use sockaddr_storage struct to store
                       // client info coming in, not using addrinfo as done for host (local) 
                       // by calling getaddrinfo for resolution, which stores results in 
                       // the more convenient addrinfo struct

  struct sockaddr_storage client; // Sockaddr storage struct is larger than sockaddr_in, 
                                  // can be used both for IPv4 and IPv6

  pthread_attr_t attr; // Thread attribute
  int i; // Thread iterator

  /* Start of main program */

  if (argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: no port provided\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  memset(&flags, 0, sizeof(flags));
  flags.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // Use IPv4 or IPv6, whichever
  flags.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // TCP
  flags.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // Set address for me 

  if (getaddrinfo(NULL, argv[1], &flags, &host_info) < 0)
  {
    perror("Couldn't read host info for socket start");
    exit(-1);
  }

  serv_sockfd = socket(host_info->ai_family, host_info->ai_socktype, host_info->ai_protocol);

  if (serv_sockfd < 0)
  {
    perror("Error opening socket");
    exit(-1);
  }

  if (bind(serv_sockfd, host_info->ai_addr, host_info->ai_addrlen) < 0)
  {
    perror("Error on binding");
    exit(-1);
  }

  freeaddrinfo(host_info); // Don't need this struct anymore

  pthread_attr_init(&attr); // Creating thread attributes
  pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr, SCHED_FIFO); // FIFO scheduling for threads 
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED); // Don't want threads (particualrly main)
                                                               // waiting on each other


  listen(serv_sockfd, QUEUE_SIZE); // Pass in socket file descriptor and the size of the backlog queue 
                                   // (how many pending connections can be in queue while another request
                                   // is handled)
  addr_size = sizeof(client);
  i = 0;

  while (1)
  {
    if (i == NTHREADS) // So that we don't access a thread out of bounds of the thread pool
    {
      i = 0;
    }

    new_sockfd = accept(serv_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &addr_size);

    if (new_sockfd < 0)
    {
      perror("Error on accept");
      exit(-1);
    }

    pthread_create(&threadid[i++], &attr, &threadworker, (void *) new_sockfd);
    sleep(0); // Giving threads some CPU time
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**And the Client Code is:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 256 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int sockfd, rw;
  struct addrinfo flags;
  struct addrinfo *server_info;

  char *buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);

  if (argc < 4)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./client <hostname/address> <port> <file_path>");
    exit(-1);
  }

  memset(&flags, 0, sizeof(flags)); // Clear so we're not working with garbage
  flags.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // IPv4 or IPv6 doesn't matter
  flags.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // TCP
  flags.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // get the IP for me

  if (getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &flags, &server_info) < 0) { // Resolve host based on CMD args
    perror("Couldn't find host");
    exit(-1);
  }

  sockfd = socket(server_info->ai_family, server_info->ai_socktype, server_info->ai_protocol); // Initialize socket

  if (connect(sockfd, server_info->ai_addr, server_info->ai_addrlen) < 0)
  {
    perror("Couldn't conenct...");
    exit(-1);
  }

  //printf("Connection established, please enter a message:\n");
  bzero(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
  //fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE - 1, stdin);

  //char buffer[100];
  FILE *f;
  size_t read=0;
  if((f=fopen(argv[3],"r"))==NULL){
    printf("Failed");
    exit(-1);
  }
    //fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    //len = ftell(f);
  //while (fgets(buffer, strlen(buffer), f) != NULL)    
  //fscanf(f,"%s",buffer);
  //fread(buffer, strlen(buffer)+1, 1, f);
  do{
    read = fread(buffer,sizeof(char),BUFFER_SIZE-1, f);
    if (read > 0) //if return value is > 0
    {
            buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]='\0';
            rw = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    }
  }
  while(read == BUFFER_SIZE); //end when a read returned fewer items
    fclose(f);


    //write(sock, &len, sizeof(int));
    //write(sock, buffer, len);

  printf("the file was sent successfully");

  //rw = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer)); // Sending the contents of the buffer - writes using socket file descriptor
  if (rw < 0)
  {
    perror("Failed to send message");
    exit(-1);
  }

  /*bzero(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
  rw = read(sockfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE); // Read the ENTIRE buffer because we don't know stlen yet 

  if (rw < 0)
  {
    perror("Error reading from socket");
    exit(-1);
  }

  printf("The message is: %s\n", buffer);
  */
  close(sockfd);
  return 0;

}
```

**My add1.txt file contains**

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
```

**The add2.txt file contains as output:**

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
############################################################################################################################################################################################################################################
```

Can anyone please advice me what are the modifications I will need then.

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: fclose(fp)????? if you don't close the file, it won't write the contents...

Comment: @fernando.reyes: thank you, I missed the basic step. But stil I got a problem. It just writes 1st line in the add2.txt excluding other lines in add1.txt

Comment: You're reading only one line with fscanf, you can try fread to read the whole file and transfer it at once

Comment: @fernando He could do that, but it is better to read line by line so he will have to use a while loop and read each line until he reaches the end of the file like this example: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080315052002AA5Gd1z

Comment: @fernando.reyes: Thank YOu. I modify the code according to your advice. But at the output file, it shows some extra characters which are not present my input file. Can you pls advice me how to remove those. The modified code and the question is on the post.

Comment: @user2015915 Try setting fread to fread(buffer,sizeof(char),BUFFER_SIZE - 1, f); It looks like it might of got junk data when reading from the file.

Comment: @JohnOdom: I modify the code according to your advice, but the problem remains. PLease see my modified code above.

Comment: @user2015915 Hmm...Could you try buffer[BUFFER_SIZE - 1]='\0';? Lol I'm just throwing stuff out there that I think could work, trying to do two different projects at once :P

Comment: @JohnOdom: I just tried. I just modify: read = fread(buffer,sizeof(char),BUFFER_SIZE, f); and buffer[BUFFER_SIZE-1]='\0'; BUt the result is same. I know that I am bothering you. I am sorry for such queries.

Comment: @user2015915 No it is not a bother, I'm glad to help you :). When I have free time I will try to help again.

Comment: When printing the file you'r printing a fwrite with BUFFER_SIZE, but your input file is not a multiple of BUFFER_SIZE, if you're sending the while file in a message with may work with fprintf(file, "%s", buffer) and it will not print anything after the \0 you have from the complete file.

Comment: @fernando.reyes: Thank you very much. It works finally. Thank you fernando and John for giving me your precious time.Fernando, Can you please advice me how to i save add1.txt file as add1.txt. I mean, here in server code I modify the filename by hard coding. But I want that add1.txt will come to the server ans save as it is. Is there any advice from you?And surely I will not follow this procedure for storing other file formats, na?(so many questions have asked.Sory to bother you.)

Comment: If you keep a counter of the files that you receive you can create the filename with sprintf, like: sprintf(filename, "add%d.txt", counter); and as far as you keep the counter accurate with the next file number, you will be creating add1, add2, add3, etc filenames

Comment: @fernando.reyes: Yes, you are right in a way.But it will not work when any one sends file 'x.txt'. it will not save in the server as x.txt then. I am now looking for such a mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call fclose on File *fp (server code) and File *f (client code) after you are done reading/writing the file. You did close the connection between the client and server, but you did not close the file stream which is probably the cause of the files being empty. So in your case it will be safe to call fclose after you called fprintf (server code) and fscanf (client code).

Comment: Thank You. According to you and fernando, I just modify my code above. And i found 1st line of add1.txt has written in add2.txt. But why other lines of add1.txt has not transferred in add2.txt. I just modify my question also in the post.Can you give me any advice in this regard.